# EWS appointment reminders

Tags: exchangewebservices, appointment

I'm getting appointment items of an account by ews as CalendarItemType object... this got an item as AppointmentState.

i looked msdn and it has only (noattendees,is meeting,recieved,cancelled,forwaded values)

but how to get reminder values(snooze,dismissed e.g) and if snoozed got snooze time 
and the current status of appoinment(cancelled,deleted e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when the user chooses to "snooze" an appointment, the property [ReminderMinutesBeforeStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.reminderminutesbeforestart(EXCHG.80).aspx) is changed accordingly by Outlook (note that I am referring to the EWS Managed API).

Comment: ReminderMinutesBeforeStart value not changes at all it 's value of the time reminder get activated before the meeting time in minutes..the only change i found at CalendarItemType object is when value it is in string based like "17 Feb 2010 Wednesday 13:40-15:04."... may reminders holded in another object types??

Comment: In that case I think that the "snooze" functionality is an Outlook feature and has nothing to do with the Exchange store.

Comment: may it be accomplished with any other object type?u know also tasks has a reminder and snooze at outlook

Comment: You can access the reminders through EWS but I don't see any way to access the snooze settings.